# Dynamically Changing CSS using Javascript on a HTML table depending on a specific event

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

Am working on an application that has **2 tables on the 
left side and 2 rows on the right side**, on the table when 
the user selects any number, the td values are dynamically 
added on the rows on the right side.

This works as expected but I'm trying to add a functionality using JS whereby if the user **hovers on any input on the row (on the right side) 
it changes to green** and all the corresponding values/td on the 
table (left side) **whose values match with the row the user hovered on** background color immediately changes to green.

For instance, if the user **hovers on any input a row on the right side** which has these values: 7, 9, 4, 3, 5  **the specific input background color field should change to green (which works on my code)** to the corresponding td values (7, 9, 4, 3, 5) on the table on the left side whose values **match with the specific input's row which the user hovered on** and change background color to green

Here is my attempt:

**Markup code**

```
<!--Table on the left -->
<div style="width: 140px; float: left;">
    <table id="table1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>10</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<!-- Rows on the right-->


<!--2nd table-->
<div style="width: 140px; float: left; margin-left: 12px;">
        <table id="table2">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td>6</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>7</td>
                    <td>8</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>9</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <!-- Rows on the right-->

<!-- Make sure each input has a unique id-->
<div style="width: 600px; float: right;">
    <div id="selection1">
        <input type="text" name="1" size="4" id="inp1" value="">
        <input type="text" name="2" size="4" id="inp2"  value="">
        <input type="text" name="3" size="4" id="inp3"  value="">
        <input type="text" name="4" size="4" id="inp4"  value="">
        <input type="text" name="5" size="4" id="inp5"  value="">  +
        <input style="margin-left: 20px;" type="text" name="6" size="4" id="bonus1"  value="">        
    </div>

    <div style="margin-top: 5px;" >
        <input type="text" size="4" id="inp7" value="">
        <input type="text"   size="4" id="inp8"  value="">
        <input type="text"  size="4" id="inp9"  value="">
        <input type="text"  size="4" id="inp10"  value="">
        <input type="text"  size="4" id="inp11"  value="">  +
        <input style="margin-left: 20px;" type="text"  size="4" id="bonus2"  value="">        
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript Code**

```
<script>
        // window.onload = function () { alert("Js working!") };

        let currentInput = 1; 
        let bonusInput = 1;

        $("#table1 td").on('click',function(event){
            //gets the number associated with the click
            let num = $(this).text(); 
            //set it to input's value attribute
            $("#inp" + currentInput++).attr("value",num); 
        });

        //Bonus input
        $("#table2").on('click',function(event){
            let bon = event.target.textContent;
            $("#bonus" + bonusInput++).attr("value",bon);
        });

        $("input").hover( function(event) {
            let num = $(this).attr("value");
            if (num) {
                //Change input color on hover
                $(this).css("backgroundColor","green");
                //Change tables specific input bgcolor on hover
                $("#table1 td").each(function() {
                    if ($(this).text() === num) $(this).css("backgroundColor","green");
                });
                $("#table2 td").each(function() {
                    if ($(this).text() === num) $(this).css("backgroundColor","green");
                });
            }   
            }, 
            function(event) {
                //Change input color on hover out
                $(this).css("backgroundColor","white");
                //Change specific table bgcolor on hover out
                $("#table1 td").each(function() {
                    $(this).css("backgroundColor","orange");
                });
                $("#table2 td").each(function() {
                    $(this).css("backgroundColor","orange");
                });   
            });
    </script>
```

---

Comment: grab the value of the current on hover with jquery and then go to the other tables and [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/). If you give a snippet I can start from (that works here on SO) I can show you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe what you want is having this code:

```
    let currentInput = 1; 
    let bonusInput = 1;

    $("#table1 td").on('click',function(event){
        //gets the number associated with the click
        let num = $(this).text(); 
        //set it to input's value attribute
        $("#inp" + currentInput++).attr("value",num); 
    });

    //Bonus input
    $("#table2").on('click',function(event){
        let bon = event.target.textContent;
        $("#bonus" + bonusInput++).attr("value",bon);
    });

    $("input").hover( function(event) {
        //alert($('#selection1 input').serialize());
        //let num = $(this).attr("value");
        let parent = $(this).parent();
        $(parent.children()).each(function (index, element) {
        let num = $(element).val();
          if (num) {
              //Change input color on hover
              $(this).css("backgroundColor","green");
              //Change tables bgcolor on hover
              $("#table1 td").each(function() {
                  if ($(this).text() === num) $(this).css("backgroundColor","green");
              });
              $("#table2 td").each(function() {
                  if ($(this).text() === num) $(this).css("backgroundColor","green");
              });
          }
        });
        }, 
        function(event) {
            //Change input color on hover out
             let parent = $(this).parent();
                 $(parent.children()).each(function (index, element) {

            $(element).css("backgroundColor","white");
            });
            //Change tables bgcolor on hover out
            $("#table1 td").each(function() {
                $(this).css("backgroundColor","orange");
            }); 
        });
```

Comment: Changed it but the effect is still the same..I want when the user hovers on the input on the row ,, Javascript captures all the input fields of that row and highlights them on the table ..

Comment: Isnt' this what you are looking for ?

https://jsfiddle.net/kvaxq5Lw/

If not please provide a screenshot of the desired behavior

Comment: Please check this js fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/w02ks5fd/   I want when the user hovers on the input on the row ,, Javascript captures all the input fields of that row and highlights them on the table as green ..

Comment: Stil waiting for a response from your end

Comment: ,, Apologies,, I had stepped out of my computer for a while,, It works fine,,,When the user hovers in on the row the background color changes to green which is fine,, Just a polite request .. Would like when he hovers out the background color of the row reverts back to white and this affects only the table on the left (without affecting the table on the right) ..